# Unable to convert Avisynth script in ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, script

I tried create a video file from the `AviSynth` script using this command (in Windows 7):

```
ffmpeg  -i  file.avs  file.mp4
```

and I got this message:

```
[avisynth @ 05000e60] AviSynth version is too old. Please upgrade to either
                      AviSynth 2.6 >= RC1 or AviSynth+ >= r1718.
                      file.avs: Unknown error occurred
```

Very clear recommendation (as I use `AviSynth+ 0.1 (r1576, x86)`) but I'm not able to find an newer version, neither for `AviSynth`, nor for `AviSynth+`.

Nevertheless, it was probably only an recommendation. The most important part is indeed this:

```
                      file.avs: Unknown error occurred
```

So I changed the content of the `file.avs` - I put only one command into it, enough simple and stupid, so my `file.avs` now looks like:

```
version
```

*No change.* The same message. So I kindly ask for an advice what to do.

(I tried it with versions `3.2.2` and `2.8.4` of `ffmpeg`, both of them report  `--enable-libxavs` in their configuration and `D  avisynth  AviSynth script` in their file formats obtained by `ffmpeg -formats`.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From FFmpeg source code:

> On Windows, FFmpeg supports AviSynth interface version 6 or higher.
>   This includes AviSynth 2.6 RC1 or higher, and AviSynth+ r1718 or
>   higher, and excludes 2.5 and the 2.6 alphas.

From [doom9](https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1718841#post1718841):

> The decision to drop support for anything below 2.6 RC1 was due to
>   catastrophic header incompatibilities between 2.5 and 2.6 RC1* and the
>   maintenance burden (and potential licensing minefield that could mean
>   any additional 2.5 support would violate GPL) that would be incurred
>   by trying to continue to support 2.5 while using properly updated 2.6
>   headers.

---

Get AviSynth+ r2420 from 
https://github.com/pinterf/AviSynthPlus/releases/tag/r2420-MT